# Programmatic retweeting with Python's twitter library

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm trying to programmatically retweet various tweets with Python's `python-twitter` library. The code executes without error, but the RT never happens. Here's the code:

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth

# my actual keys are here
OAUTH_TOKEN = ""
OAUTH_SECRET = ""
CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

result = t.statuses.retweets._id(_id=444320020122722304)

print(result)
```

The only output is an empty list. How can I get it to actually RT the tweet?

Comment: Which `twitter` library are you using, and where does the `OAuth` class come from?

Comment: I'm using `python-twitter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the answers posted here were instrumental in finding the final code that works. Thank you all! The code that works with the `python-twitter` library is below.

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth

# my actual keys are here
OAUTH_TOKEN = ""
OAUTH_SECRET = ""
CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

result = t.statuses.retweet(id=444320020122722304)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

answer using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy):

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.retweet(tweetID)  # e.g. api.retweet(445959276855435264)

# or for use from command line:
# api.retweet(sys.argv[1])
```

hope that helps? I'm guessing my ACCESS key and secret are equivalent to your OAUTH token and secret..

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention but I'm assuming you're using python-twitter library:

Try using (from the [doc](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py))
`def PostRetweet(self, original_id, trim_user=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Check out Twython's retweet function under Core Interface here https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html and the associated Twitter API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid documents.

Also this post on here [Posting a retweet via twython gives 401 whereas I can easily access the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313165/posting-a-retweet-via-twython-gives-401-whereas-i-can-easily-access-the-timeline).

Comment: Sorry for short post! I'm in the bath, on my phone, and trying to keep it away from the water! Lol!